# Sync SonarTS Quality profile with tslint.json Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

I am currently using SonarTS to analyse my Angular 5/6 App.
I am running tslint locally using the tslint.json ruleset and have cleared all errors/warnings.
After sonar analysis it is apparent that the TsLint quality profile in SonarTS and the tslint.json are not using the same ruleset.
Is there anyway to get SonarQube to use my project tslint.json and create a quality profile based on that ruleset?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to do that, and note that not all TSLint rules are available through SonarTS. 
So I would recommend:

1. Create profile with the rules you want manually

or

2. Use a new feature allowing import of tslint reports (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Importing+TSLint+and+ESLint+issues+for+TypeScript+files), but until SQ 7.2 is released you can use it only on [SonarCloud](http://sonarcloud.io).

P.S. [This page](https://jira.sonarsource.com/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20RSPEC%20AND%20%22Covered%20Languages%22%20%3D%20TypeScript%20AND%20TSLint%20is%20not%20EMPTY) can help you to find matching rules